# python selenium can't do basic seach on a website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning selenium right now and I am trying to search on google using selenium. But I keep getting errors and I cant figure out why.

here's my code:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search_bar.send_keys("twitter")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

and here's the error statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/someone/Desktop/sel_tut/locating_elems.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 122, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/n./.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/117.0.5938.62/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

I already checked my selenium and chromedriver version to make sure they are compatible and tried switching to searching by id but I still get errors

```
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "APjFqb")
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the search. It's crashing when you try to create the webdriver. It seems like Selenium may not be installed properly.

Comment: Return code -9 means the process was killed (SIGKILL).  Does this happen after 10 second, when you "quit" everything?

Comment: @Barmar should I delete and reinstall?

Comment: @TimRoberts nope, the google website did not even appear. it crashed roughly after 2 or 3 seconds after I press run

Comment: Can't hurt to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Service unexpectedly exited' error appears to be related to compatibility issues with the ChromeDriver you have installed. It seems you have already addressed compatibility concerns with both of selenium and chromedriver , but it's also essential to verify compatibility with macOS.

Here is the link to download the arm64 version of chrome driver.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11517

Just rule out this possibility, I suggest you upgrade both of them to the latest version.

```
pip install --upgrade webdriver_manager
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

Let's see what happens.